# How do i link multiple orders to as single customer django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models, Customer and Order, Order is linked to Customer via the foreignkey, my problem comes from relating a customer with multiple orders, in my customer_list.html i did this linking a name to a pk:

```
{% for customer in customer_list %}
....href="{%url 'order_app:order_detail' pk=customer.pk %}"> Customer Name..
{% endfor %}
```

And i want to display all the orders of that particular customer in order_detail.html for e.g:

```
  {% for order in customer.orders.all %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{order.pk}}</td>
            <td>{{order.project_title}}</td>
            <td>{{order.order_date}}</td>
            <td>{{order.order_status}}</td>
            <td>{{order.amount}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

This method doesnt work, and i cant seem to figure out how to fix this 
Thank you for your help

Views Customer File:

```
class CustomerListView(ListView):
model = Customer
template_name = 'order_app/customer_list.html'
```

Views Order Detail:

```
class OrderDetailView(DetailView):
model = Order
```

Models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
contact = models.CharField(max_length=20)
def __str__(self):  # string representation of the object (e.g Haris instead of Order Object 1
    return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
project_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
order_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
amount = models.IntegerField()
order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
upload = models.FileField(upload_to = 'uploads/')
comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Comment: post the view function used for this template and also your models

Comment: That should be `customer.order_set.all`, not `customer.orders.all`.

Comment: @Exprator I added the view function and models

Comment: Specifically what is not working? Is the issue with the customer list, or the list of orders on the order detail page? Are you seeing an error, or nothing rendered?